# How to show alerts to user in Spring MVC (Triggered by some DataBase fields)?

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring MVC based application. It's backed by MySQL database. Following are my requirements:

- Each registered user in my application will be assigned tasks. Each task has a **Next_Action_Date** field associated with it.
- If a task is not completed (marked by **IS_COMPLETE**) and the **Next_Action_Date** is approaching (within next 2 hrs), I need to show alert messages (after every 30 mins) about the approaching deadLine.
- Most importantly, each user will be notified about tasks assigned to him only.

Please suggest a design/approach to implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Spring 4, as it supports [WebSockets](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)
2. If Tomcat, use Tomcat 7.0.52+ (for WebSocket support)
3. Use [Spring TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) to check database if need to send an alert

Comment: Can you please elaborate how WebSockets will help in this scenario? If possible please direct me to some tutorial or code snippets.

Comment: @Sumit WebSocket allows you to send a message from the web server to the web browser clients, without polling. So if the server detects that an alert should be shown, it pushes a websocket message to the browser, which can then show an alert.

Comment: I tried to implement the same as suggested by you using Stomp and SockJs for Spring 4.0 WebSocket. EveryThing is working fine except the fact that my server is pushing messages/notifications to all the users. How can I modify my application to send it to specific users. I implemented my functionality similar to one mentioned at [WebSockets](http://gerrydevstory.com/2014/03/04/stock-ticker-demo-webapp-using-spring-4-websocket/)

As mentioned above, I may have multiple members logged in but only some of them will be required to view the notifications.

Comment: @Sumit you can integrate w spring security and use the sendToUser() function